# Differentiate $y^{1-n}=z$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

How can I differentiate $y^{1-n} = z$ to obtain $$(1-n)y^{-n}\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dz}{dx}$$

---

I am stuck at why differentiation of $y$ is done here, if differentiation is w.r.t. $x$, as $y$ should be treated as constant .

Comment: $(y^k)'=ky'y^{k-1}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your [recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2257221/solve-the-differential-equation-x-fracdydx-y-x3y6), I assume the reason you are asking this is because you are solving a [Bernoulli differential equation](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Bernoulli.aspx). When solving these, we assume that $y$ and $z$ are **functions** of $x$. Therefore, you should **not** be considering $y$ as a constant, but you should be considering $y:=y(x)$, $z:=z(y)$.

---

$$z:=z(y), y:=y(x) \implies z:=z(y(x))$$
Therefore, it becomes evident that we should use the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule)!

> In Leibniz Notation, this is:
>   $$\frac{dz}{dx}=\frac{dz}{dy}\cdot \frac{dy}{dx} \tag{1}$$

We can find $\frac{dz}{dy}$ by using the [Power Rule of Differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_rule):
$$\frac{d}{dy}(y^\alpha)=\alpha y^{\alpha-1}$$
Hence, in our case where $\alpha=1-n$, this would be:
$$\frac{dz}{dy}=\frac{d}{dy}\left(y^{1-n}\right)=(1-n)y^{1-n-1}=(1-n)y^{-n}$$
Substituting into $(1)$, we get the result required:
$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\frac{dz}{dx}=(1-n)y^{-n}\cdot \frac{dy}{dx}}$$

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you know $(y^k)'= ky'y^{k-1}$. To answer your wonder: why we should differentiate $y$.

The question did not explicitly say that, but according to the convention, the most reasonable inference is that both $y$ and $z$ in the equation are functions of $x$, i.e. $y(x)^{1-n} =z(x)$