# Solve the differential equation $x\frac{dy}{dx} + y = x^3y^6$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Solve the differential equation ?$$x\frac{dy}{dx} + y = x^3y^6$$

---

I thought to solve this using bernoulli's equation, but got stuck in the middle.

**My try** :-

First of all, divide the equation by $xy^6$, I have $$y^{-6}\frac{dy}{dx} + \frac{y^{-5}}{x} = x^2$$

Now, assume $y^{-5} = z$, but i am stuck at how differentiating this becomes $$-5y^{-6}\frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{dz}{dx}$$

AM I missing something here ?

Comment: To differentiate, use the product rule. For example, if $w = w(t)$ and you want to differentiate $w^{2}$ with respect to $t$, then $$\frac{d}{dt} w^{2}(t) = \frac{d}{dt} w(t) w(t) = \frac{dw}{dt} \cdot w(t) + w(t) \cdot \frac{dw}{dt} = 2 w'(t) w(t)$$ Now try it for $z = y^{-5}$

Comment: @Mattos, If differentiation is w.r.t $x$, then everything else must be treated as a constant. But, here  that is not being followed ?

Comment: $y = y(x)$ in your problem. So no, $y$ is not to be treated as constant. It is an arbitrary function of $x$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With $z = y^{-5}$ you have that $$\frac{dz}{dx} = -5y^{-6} \frac{dy}{dx}$$ (remember, $z = z(y)$ and $y = y(x)$, so implicit differentiation is necessary).

You can justify this to yourself better by observing the following equality: $$\frac{dz}{dx} = \frac{dz}{dy} \frac{dy}{dx} $$
Substituting these quantities in, you get:
$$-\frac1{5} \frac{dz}{dx} + \frac{z}{x} = x^2$$
Multiplying by $-5$,
$$\frac{dz}{dx} - \frac{5}{x}z= -5x^2$$
This is now a first order linear equation, which you can solve using an integrating factor

Answer (score 1):

$$x\frac{dy}{dx}+y=x^3y^6 \Rightarrow xdy+ydx=x^3y^6dx \Rightarrow d(xy)=\frac{(xy)^6}{x^3}dx \Rightarrow \frac{d(xy)}{(xy)^6}=\frac{1}{x^3}dx \\ \Rightarrow \frac{-1}{5(xy)^5}=\frac{-1}{2x^2}+c_1\Rightarrow \frac{1}{5(xy)^5}=\frac{1}{2x^2}+c \Rightarrow y=\sqrt[5]{\frac{2}{5x^3(1+2cx^2)}}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$y^{-6}\frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{1}{xy^5}=x^2$$
Put $y^{-5}=t$
$$\frac{dt}{ dx}. \frac{-1}{6}+\frac{t}{x}=x^2$$

Rest is simple Bernoulli's Principle i.e.:

$$\frac{dy}{dx} + Py=Q$$
$$\int d(I y)=\int I Q.dx +C$$

where $$I=e^{\int P.dx}$$

Comment: I am aware of BP, but how that dt/dx comes.  If differentiation is w.r.t x, then everything else must be treated as a constant. But, here that is not being followed ?

Comment: If $y=t$ then $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dt}{dx} $ @JonGarrick

Comment: @JonGarrick $t$ is a function of $x$.